# Stumps haul out

Tags: outdoor, removal, tree, excavation, digging

I have a mound in front of my house with two stumps in it (shown below). I have a quote for the excavation of the mound which includes the removal of dirt.

The difference between hauling the excavated stumps out and leaving them on the property is $600. Is it worth it to have them hauled out? Or can I use my EGO saw to poke at the stumps. If I can reduce them to fire pit sized chunks, even I go through 8 chains, I will have saved $500.

[image]

Comment: Matters of opinion and finances are off-topic here.

Comment: You should be able to get both of them ground down and the roots "chased" for $150-$200.  To do two stumps that close together should not be much more than doing one.

Comment: Drill them full of holes, fill the holes with mushroom spawn, wait a while, eat....

Comment: dump burning charcoal on them. wait. repeat as needed. add a fan to speed things up. bath salts can work too if you're not in a hurry.

Answer (score 1):

I am dealing with a similar dilemma. I decided to grind them. Here in AZ it costs $200 for stump grinding and they will grind down 6-8" below grade. You may want to look into that option.

Comment: Here in Philly, it's 1200

Answer (score 1):

I regularly burn stumps after pulling them out one caution if you are in an area that requires the fire to be put out at night stumps may reignite hours later, I usually cover them with dirt , they will sometimes smolder for months and I mean 8+ weeks smoke coming out when the smoke stops I mix all the dirt with some horse manure and instant potting soil / garden dirt. So I think it’s worth it to burn them if allowed in your area.

Answer (score 1):

Not easy but dig out the soil around the stumps so you can saw them without dulling so many  chains. I just had an 18" diameter oak cut down and the stump taken out to at least a depth of 6 " below grade. For a couple days (no hurry) I dug up all soil down to about 8". Used a hose to wash soil away from the roots.I asked the tree guy to get as deep as he could. He got surprisingly deep without changing chains but I bet he needed to sharpen it. It was 5 or $ 600 to take down the big 60 ft tree and stump but labor is not high in E.TX.

Comment: They'll be out of the ground. The $600 is just for the haul away.